# Сериализация Enum в WCF

Tags: c#, json, wcf

Как можно сделать вот это:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "Enums")]
public enum Foo
{
   [EnumMember(Value = "foo")] 
   Item
}
```

Сериализованным как:

```
if (typeof(Enums.Foo) === 'undefined') {
Enums.Foo= function() { throw Error.invalidOperation(); }
Enums.Foo.prototype = {Item: "foo"}
Enums.Foo.registerEnum('Enums.Foo', true);
}
```

А то сериализация данного `Enum` идёт как:

```
if (typeof(Enums.Foo) === 'undefined') {
Enums.Foo= function() { throw Error.invalidOperation(); }
Enums.Foo.prototype = {foo: 0}
Enums.Foo.registerEnum('Enums.Foo', true);
}
```

А мне нужно значение строковое, я понимаю, что `[EnumMember(Value = "foo")]` задаёт имя, а не значение, но всё же возможно ли это?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cколько не искал, данной возможности для `ENUM` [нету](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/ea5c6cb1-bf9d-4f87-9f22-279185c638c5) .